# When binding UITableView with RxTableViewRealmDataSource, swipe for delete is disabled

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, rx-swift

I'm trying to implement a simple TableView with Realm DataSource.
First, I create a ChangeSet

```
cars = realm.objects(CarModel.self)    
carChangeset = Observable.changeset(from: cars, synchronousStart: false).observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
```

and I created an instance of `RxTableViewRealmDataSource`

```
let dataSource = RxTableViewRealmDataSource<CarModel>(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: CarListTableViewCell.self) { (cell, ip, element) in
    cell.viewModel = CarDetailViewModel(car: element)
}
```

Then, I bound my changeset to the tableview

```
carChangeset
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.realmChanges(dataSource))
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

I run my project, but, no matter how I swipe a cell in my TableView, the "delete" button will never appear.

After looking for a solution to my problem, I read that, in order to a TableView to present the "red delete" button when swiping, the DataSource delegate must implement `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. As `RxTableViewRealmDataSource` is not declared `open` on the original distribution, and I don't want to modify the sources, I created an extension that implements this function:

```
extension RxTableViewRealmDataSource where E: CarModel {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            print("Should Delete car")
        }
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Still nothing. My TableView does not react to the swipe gesture.

Is this a bug on the RxRealm/RxRealmDataSource implementation? Am I doing something wrong? Or do I missed something?

Thanks in advance,